# Is there a way to update google my places programmaticay

Tags: google-maps

I know I can generate a KML file and upload manually to google map but is there an API or a way to do it programmatically ? 
I can't find anything in the doc of the Google Map Api V3 ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions

Comment: is it an answer or just a comment ? Also, can I update a private map with it ?